# Duplicates record should not be allowed

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When i select the item from dropdown and it will add to the table if the user will add it again it should show error that item is already added.

```
<select id="dropdownUsers"></select>
<table border="1" id="tableshow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>unit Price</td>
            <td>qunatity</td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody id="tabledata"></tbody>
</table>
```

ajax call to bind the table

```
 var val = $("#dropdownUsers").val();
                             $.ajax({
                                 dataType: 'json',
                                 type: 'POST',
                                 contentType: "application/Json; charset=utf-8",
                                 url: '/Home/fillDropdownbyids',
                                 data: JSON.stringify({ id: val }),
                                 success: function (response) {
                                     $("#id").append(response.user.iUserInfoId + " ")
                                     var tr = '';


                                     tr += '<tr class="row"><td class="rowid' + val + '">' + response.user.iUserInfoId + '</td><td>' + response.user.strFirstName + '</td><td><input type="text" id="unittextbox' + val + '"></td><td><input type="text" id="quantextbox' + val + '" onfocusout="get(' + val + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="totaltextbox' + val + '" ></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td></tr>';


                                     $('#tabledata').append(tr);
                                 },
                             });
```

This will fetch the rows for first td from the table it will return the list of array of id

```
 $('#tableshow > tbody  > tr ').each(function (index, td) {
                     arr = $(this).find('td');
                     arrlist[index] = arr[0].innerHTML;
                     index++;
                 });
```

And i want to compare this td values with drop down selected values if it is matched then it should show the record exists else its allow to insert the data into table

Comment: Why not remove the selected element from the dropdown after it is added to the table?

Comment: Actually i allow to the user to delete the row if it was added by mistaken .so then it will create problem i can do that and on delete button i had make an ajax call but i dont want that it will go to server side every time and fetch that product by id... so ny other solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var val = $("#dropdownUsers").val();
var isAvailiable = myFunction(val);
if(isAvailiable){
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/Json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/Home/fillDropdownbyids',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: val }),
        success: function (response) {
                        $("#id").append(response.user.iUserInfoId + " ")
                         var tr = '';
                         tr += '<tr class="row"><td class="rowid' + val + '">' + response.user.iUserInfoId + '</td><td>' + response.user.strFirstName + '</td><td><input type="text" id="unittextbox' + val + '"></td><td><input type="text" id="quantextbox' + val + '" onfocusout="get(' + val + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="totaltextbox' + val + '" ></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td></tr>';
                         $('#tabledata').append(tr);
                           },
    })
} else {
    //Show error message
}

//Call this before calling myFuction();
$('#tableshow > tbody  > tr ').each(function (index, td) {
    arr = $(this).find('td');
    arrlist[index] = arr[0].innerHTML;
    index++;
});

//Function to check that value is present array or not
function myFunction(val){
    var isAvailiable = false
    for(i=0;i<arrlist.length;i++){
        if(arrlist[i] === val){
            isAvailiable = true;
        }
    }
    return isAvailiable;
}
```